# Valor de cálculo desaparecendo

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com um problema no projeto de uma calculadora que estou desenvolvendo

Tudo da calculadora funciona, menos na hora de imprimir os valores no `input` de tela: os valores aparecem e desaparecem em menos de 1 segundo, deixando o `input` em branco.

Segue o código usado:

```js
function putNum(num){
    document.getElementById('tela').value = document.getElementById('tela').value + num;
}

function limpar(){
   document.getElementById('tela').value = document.getElementById('tela').value = " ";
}

function oper(oprt){
    if(document.getElementById('tela').value != ""){
        document.getElementById('tela').value = document.getElementById('tela').value + oprt;
    } else {
        alert('Antes de realizar operações, digite um número')
    }
}

function result(){
    document.getElementById('tela').value = eval(document.getElementById('tela').value);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculadora com Botões</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='calculadora-botoes.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
      <form>
          <div id='calculadora'>
                <div id='cabecalho'>
                    <input type="textarea" name="tela" id="tela" maxlength="18">
                    <input type="submit" id="resul" value="=" onclick='result()'>
                </div>

                <table>
                    <tr> <!--Operadores-->
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" id="c" value="C" onclick='limpar()'>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class='oper' value="+" onclick='oper("+")'>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class='oper' value="-" onclick='oper("-")'>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class='oper' value="*" onclick='oper("*")'>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class='oper' value="/" onclick='oper("/")'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr><!--Números-->
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class='num' value="1" onclick='putNum(1)'>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class='num' value="2" onclick='putNum(2)'>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class='num' value="3" onclick='putNum(3)'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class='num' value="4" onclick='putNum(4)'>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class='num' value="5" onclick='putNum(5)'>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class='num' value="6" onclick='putNum(6)'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class='num' value="7" onclick='putNum(7)'>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class='num' value="8" onclick='putNum(8)'>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class='num' value="9" onclick='putNum(9)'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class='num' value="0" onclick='putNum(0)'>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
          </div>
      </form>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não precisa usar `form` no código já que vc não vai enviar nada pro servidor.

Comment: O problema está no botão `=` que está submetendo o form. Troque o type pra `type="button"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o SAM disse nos comentários basta trocar o tipo do botão.

O que acontece é que quando click ocorre o navegador tenta enviar o formulário ao servidor.

Onde esta:

```
<input type="submit" id="resul" value="=" onclick='result()'>
```

Faça:

```
<input type="button" id="resul" value="=" onclick='result()'>
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na falta de alguma configuração para travar o envio do formulário.

Isso significa que, quando tem um `<input>` do tipo `type="submit"` ele vai enviar essas informações para uma próxima página, como esse botão não está em fomulário ele está redirecionando para a própria página, olhe a URL que está sendo carregada `http://www.exemplo.com/?tela=123456` essa parte do texto `?tela=123456` significa que você está fazendo um [envio por GET](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php).

Mas não se preocupe com esse termos se estiver complicado, seu problema é simples de resolver, você pode fazer é trocando os `<input>` por botões de link, já que não é um formulário, e colocando o um elemento de link `<a aria-label="botão com valor 1">`.

Seu codigo em HTML vai ficar algo parecido com isso:

```
<!-- HTLML -->
<a id="resul" href="#" aria-label="Botão de valor 1" onclick="funcao()">Exemplo de botão</a>
```

E seu código javascript vai ficar assim:

```
//javasctipt
function funcao(){

    console.log("CLICK");

}
```

Caso seja seja mais simples para resolver seu problema você pode alterar o `type` de `submit` para um simples `button`, nas boas praticas eu não recomendo isso, mas já que é para estudo, você pode alterar para não perder tempo re-escrevendo seu código.

Comment: Não tem porque interceptar e matar o evento submit, quando basta apenas trocar o tipo de botão.

Comment: Se isso ajuda, geralmente é interceptado para que não carregue a página, como em formulários de cadastro ou de informações, assim a página fica dinâmica, então vou adaptar minha resposta para que ta ajude.

Comment: Pronto agora ajustei a pergunta para o que você precisa e acho que respondi o que estava ocorrendo, me avisa se isso responder a sua pergunta, caso isso tenha te satisfeito, você pode fechar essa pergunta como uma pergunta correta.

Comment: Eu preciso? Não cara, você está equivocado. Eu disse que não havia necessidade de  interceptar e matar evento, inclusive você não foi negativado, https://imgur.com/a/5JavG3m, eu havia dado um upvote na sua primeira versão de resposta mas conforme foi mudando ficou fora de propósito tanto que eu tive escrever uma resposta para não confundir o AP e acabei removendo o voto a favor e estou pensando em negativá-la por ter transformado uma coisa simples em algo tão cunfuso.

Comment: Eu não reclamei que eu fui negativado, e não fico por ser, se eu estiver errado eu vou estar, esse meu post está explicando os seguinte, 1. Porque isso ocorre, 2. como resolver, ai eu comentei para as pessoas do stack overflow para de negativar as perguntas, "negativaram vc e eu subi um ponto", eu não estou bravo com ninguem.

Comment: Eu comentei isso porque em todo post que eu vejo sempre tem gente que não sabe responder e negativa as resposta das pessoas. Me desculpe se isso ficou confuso.

Comment: Independente do motivo (se foi reclamação, desabafo ou o que for), discussões sobre o funcionamento do site (incluindo votos e suas motivações, etc) devem ser feitas no [meta], por isso eu removi o comentário da sua resposta. Mas antes eu sugiro que faça uma pesquisa lá no meta, pois essa questão de votos negativos e reclamações variadas já foi discutida várias vezes. Exemplo: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/652/112052 (mas se buscar lá vai encontrar vários outros)

Comment: Só quero adiantar que nem sempre o negativo é de "quem não sabe responder". Na verdade os motivos podem ser diversos (o comentário acima do Augusto, por exemplo, ele disse que pensou em negativar e explicou o motivo - que vc pode até discordar, mas veja que o motivo não é "eu não sei responder", tanto que ele até escreveu uma resposta). Enfim, não vou me alongar porque esse tipo de discussão deve ser feita no [meta] (só quis "dar um pitaco" aqui, mas se quiser abrir a discussão no meta, nos falamos lá)

Comment: Tudo bem, mas a maioria das questões do stack overflow brasileiros são negativadas porque alguém não soube responder e foi embora, isso digrede com a comunidade. e mais uma vez, me desculpa se isso pareceu confuso.